# Hiding a LinkButton in DataList

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-3.5

Hi someone can tell me how to hide a LinkButton inside a DataList?

I've tried to do this but I do not work:

```
 protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (var item in listanews)
        {
            DataList container = dlgestionenews;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.IdNews))
            {

                DataListItem itemdatalist = null;


                foreach (DataListItem itemdl in container.Items)
                {

                    foreach (Control control in itemdatalist.Controls)
                    {

                        if (control.GetType().FullName == "LinkButton")
                        {
                            ((LinkButton)control).Visible = false;

                        }

                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (DataListItem dli in yourDataListControl.Items)
{
    LinkButton lbLinkButton = (LinkButton)dli.FindControl("yourLinkButtonID");
    if (lbLinkButton != null)
    {
         lbLinkButton.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move this code to the

```
protected virtual void OnItemDataBound(
    DataListItemEventArgs e
)
```

event. In this event, you should use the `e.Item.FindControl('LinkButtonID')` method for the finding your control

More info is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.onitemdatabound%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)